# In SQL how to JOIN and then GROUP BY a field that contains Null or int

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made a SQL query that joined three tables together but duplicate rows shown in result. i try to resolve this problem by using **GROUP BY** statement but this way raise error because:

```
OR "allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore"."id" IS NULL
```

line saying that `allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore` can not exist. my current query is below:

```
SELECT
    "activities_baseactivity" . "id"
    ,"allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore" . "activity_id"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "activity_type_name"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "language_type"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "other_language"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "date_created"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "date_modified"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "creator_id"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "modifier_id"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "show_in_homepage"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "professor_id"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "attachment"
    ,"activities_baseactivity" . "state"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "baseactivity_ptr_id"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "score"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "ratio"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "score1"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "score2"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "judgment_result"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "bpm_process_id"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "judgment_date"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "position"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "edu_id"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "course_title"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "thesis_title_fa"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "thesis_title_en"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "start_date"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "defense_date"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "student_name_fa"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "student_name_en"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "place_of_study_id"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "department_id"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "external_unit"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "educational_group_id"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "country_id"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "number_of_unit"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "project_type"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "project_state"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "approved_date"
    ,"activities_thesis" . "assignment_number"
    ,"allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore" . "college_score"
    ,"allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore" . "university_score"
    FROM
    "activities_thesis" INNER JOIN "activities_baseactivity"
        ON (
        "activities_thesis" . "baseactivity_ptr_id" = "activities_baseactivity" . "id"
        ) INNER JOIN "accounts_contributor"
        ON (
        "accounts_contributor" . "baseactivity_id" = "activities_baseactivity" . "id"
        ) LEFT JOIN "allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore"
        ON (
    ("accounts_contributor" . "id" = "allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore" . "contributor_id"
          OR "allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore"."id" IS NULL
        )
        AND "accounts_contributor" . "profile_id" = 253
        )
    WHERE
    (
        "activities_baseactivity" . "professor_id" = 253
        AND "activities_baseactivity" . "state" = 2
        AND "activities_thesis" . "defense_date" < '2014-01-21'
        AND "activities_thesis" . "defense_date" >= '2013-01-20'
AND "activities_baseactivity" . "id" NOT IN (32161, 32676, 32677, 32679, 32680, 32681, 32682, 32683, 32150, 32164, 19519))
GROUP BY "activities_thesis" . "baseactivity_ptr_id", "activities_baseactivity" . "id", "allame_secretaries_forms_contributorcommissionsscore" . "activity_id"
```

**How to resolve this problem?**

Comment: Using just GROUP BY doesn't help, since you're not aggregating the data in any way.

Comment: Maybe you would need [DISTINCT](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/)

Comment: I would start by simplifying the query (add and use aliases, remove excessive parentheses, *maybe* rewrite the `LEFT JOIN ... NULL` into a `not exists(...)` form)

Comment: You also don't need all those double quotes.

Comment: Thanks all, @Sami-Kuhmonen please write an answer to get reputation ;)

Comment: double quotes used because this query writes in body of second language.

Comment: Please present your code in a human-readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `GROUP BY` you need to have all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, otherwise you will get an error.

You can also use [DISTINCT](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/) to remove duplicate rows from the results.